# Evaluating the triple integral $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\left(\int_{x^2+y^2}^{2}xdz\right)dy\right)dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\left(\int_{x^2+y^2}^{2}xdz\right)dy\right)dx$$

Sketch the region of integration and evaluate the integral by expressing the order of integration as dxdydz.

Here's what I have done(or thought of) so far: Basically, we have to integrate the function $f(x,y,z)=x$ in the region between the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$and the plane $z=2$ over a quarter of a plane disc of radius $\sqrt2$ in the first quadrant. That should allow me to complete the sketch of the region of integration.

Now, on to the integration: The above integral can also be written as: $$\int_{?}^{?}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}xdx\right)dy\right)dz$$ and here's where my problem occurs. **What should come in place of those question marks in the third integral** Evaluating my first two integrals left me with $\int\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}dz$. If I put $x^2+y^2$ and $2$ as the limits I would get my answer in terms of $x\;and\;y$ which is clearly unfeasible.

So please tell me...what can I do next or what have I done wrong uptil now.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\left(\int_{x^2+y^2}^{2}xdz\right)dy\right)dx
= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\left([2-(x^2+y^2)]x\right)dy\right)dx
=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\left(2x-x^3+xy^2\right)dy\right)dx
=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left((2x-x^3)\sqrt{2-x^2}+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}xy^2dy\right)dx
=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left((2x-x^3)\sqrt{2-x^2}+\frac x3(2-x^2)\sqrt{2-x^2}\right)dx$$

May it helps!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

What about writing this integral into cylindrical coordinates? All those $x^2 + y^2$ really make me think about that!